# symfony doctrine custom dql

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder, dql

In sql I have this

```
AND oir.id IS NULL
AND IF(t.work_type = 'contract' AND te.status != 2, FALSE, TRUE)
```

and I don't know how to correct create custom DQL for this

```
IF(t.work_type = 'contract' AND te.status != 2, FALSE, TRUE)
```

help, give me dql please for this IF ()
 I think logic like this

```
IF (confition and confition, (return if true), (return if false))
```

example return true or false

OR how interpretation this for queryBuilder ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember if DQL support `if`.. I think that no.
You can use `case when ... then ... else ... end` instead.

```
AND oir.id IS NULL
AND (CASE WHEN t.work_type = 'contract' AND te.status != 2 THEN FALSE ELSE TRUE END) = TRUE
```

Why do you need so `if` in where clause? You can use this expression without `if`. Just `t.work_type = 'contract' AND te.status != 2` without `if` will return same result(`true/false`) as with `if`.